# How can i close polyline object in Delphi?

Tags: delphi, image-processing, imagej

I am using this code listed below:

```
 hobj:= ImageEnVect1.AddNewObject(iekPOLYLINE, Blob.BoundingBox, clGreen);
 ImageEnVect1.PolylineClosingMode:=iecmOnNearFinish;
 ImageEnVect1.SetObjPolylinePoints(hobj,PPList);
```

And I get these not connected polygons:

[image]

How can i connect last points and first points of these polygons?

Comment: Last point equal to first point?

Comment: They are not equal.

Comment: If you want them closed, first point coordinates must be equal to last point.

Comment: Nice advice but i have more than 10 000 polygon like these. Your advice means adding more than 10 000 points, this decelerate algorithm. I am trying to find a feature of Delphi for this problem.

Comment: Have you read the documentation before asking the question?

Comment: @Kaan Your excuse to not set a last point equal to the first to close each polygon is ridiculously weak. (1) If you have 10k polygons, an extra 10k points is not bad. Looking at your sample polygons you already have hundreds of thousands of points - an extra 10k will not be a significant number more than you already have. (2) Whether you close the polygons or Delphi closes them doesn't matter - in both cases you **use the same number of closing points!***

Comment: Much thanks! I set last points equal to first points.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From documentation http://www.imageen.com/help/ImageEn/TImageEnVect.PolylineClosingMode.html

> iecmAlways means it always closes.

With iecmOnNearFinish it will close if the end position of the polyline is very close to the start.

Comment: I read documantation and tried iecmAlways but it does not work. I guess, there is a specific problem but i could not find. Much thanks for your advices.